# Binding in userControl with ViewModel.Property

Tags: c#, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm facing an issue with my bindings. I Have a HomeViewModel that has a MajorIndexViewModel in it. This MajorViewModel has a property MyNumber

In my HomeView.xaml if I bind a property Text to MajorIndexViewModel.MyNumber, I get the number displayed correctly.

But I have a MajorIndexCard.xaml usercontrol that I want in my HomeView.xaml, which should display a property (MAN, MSFT of type MajorIndex) from the MajorIndexViewModel.

The code in HomeView.xaml :

```
<UserControl x:Class="BasicTradingApp.Views.HomeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BasicTradingApp.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Test Number"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MajorIndexViewModel.MyNumber}" />
    <controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="MajorIndexViewModel.AMZN"/>
    <controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="MajorIndexViewModel.MSFT"/>
    <controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="MajorIndexViewModel.AAPL"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The code in my MajorIndexCard.xaml :

```
<UserControl x:Class="BasicTradingApp.Controls.MajorIndexCard"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:BasicTradingApp.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushPrimary1}" CornerRadius="10">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Type}"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Open price :"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Open, StringFormat={}{0:c}}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Close price :"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Close, StringFormat={}{0:c}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The code of MajorIndexViewModel :

```
public class MajorIndexViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    readonly IMajorIndexService _majorIndexService;
    public int MyNumber { get; set; } = 3;

    public MajorIndexViewModel(IMajorIndexService majorIndexService)
    {
        _majorIndexService = majorIndexService;
    }

    private MajorIndex _msft = new MajorIndex() { Type = MajorIndexSymbol.MSFT, Close = 0.0, Open = 0.0, Symbol = "msft" };
    public MajorIndex MSFT
    {
        get { return _msft; }
        set
        {
            _msft = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MSFT));
        }
    }

    private MajorIndex _aapl = new MajorIndex() { Type = MajorIndexSymbol.AAPL, Close = 0.0, Open = 0.0, Symbol = "aapl" };
    public MajorIndex AAPL
    {
        get { return _aapl; }
        set { 
            _msft = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AAPL));
        }
    }

    private MajorIndex _amzn = new MajorIndex() { Type = MajorIndexSymbol.AMZN, Close = 0.0, Open = 0.0, Symbol = "amzn" };

    public MajorIndex AMZN 
    { 
        get { return _amzn; }
        set
        {
            _amzn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AMZN));
        }
    }

    public static MajorIndexViewModel LoadMajorIndexViewModel()
    {
        MajorIndexViewModel viewModel = new MajorIndexViewModel(new MajorIndexService());
        viewModel.LoadMajorIndexes();
        return viewModel;
    }

    void LoadMajorIndexes()
    {
        _majorIndexService.GetMajorIndex(MajorIndexSymbol.MSFT).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception == null)
            {
                var data = task.Result;
                MajorIndex index = new MajorIndex
                {
                    Close = data.close,
                    Open = data.open,
                    Symbol = "msft",
                    Type = MajorIndexSymbol.MSFT
                };
                MSFT = index;
            }
           });

        _majorIndexService.GetMajorIndex(MajorIndexSymbol.AAPL).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception == null)
            {
                var data = task.Result;
                MajorIndex index = new MajorIndex
                {
                    Close = data.close,
                    Open = data.open,
                    Symbol = "aapl",
                    Type = MajorIndexSymbol.AAPL
                };
                AAPL = index;
            }
        });

        _majorIndexService.GetMajorIndex(MajorIndexSymbol.AMZN).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception == null)
            {
                var data = task.Result;
                MajorIndex index = new MajorIndex
                {
                    Close = data.close,
                    Open = data.open,
                    Symbol = "amzn",
                    Type = MajorIndexSymbol.AMZN
                };
                AMZN = index;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why I get the display of MyNumer property but not the MajorIndexes properties...

Thank you a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution... I was blocked for so long I posted here but this is just a problem of syntax. My error :

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="Test Number"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MajorIndexViewModel.MyNumber}" />
<controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="MajorIndexViewModel.AMZN"/>
<controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="MajorIndexViewModel.MSFT"/>
<controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="MajorIndexViewModel.AAPL"/>
```

```
<StackPanel>
    <controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="{Binding MajorIndexViewModel.MSFT}"/>
    <controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="{Binding MajorIndexViewModel.AAPL}"/>
    <controls:MajorIndexCard x:Name="card3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 10" DataContext="{Binding MajorIndexViewModel.AMZN}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope this would help someone... :)